# Database - what is the different between 3 and N'3' in TSQL (Sql Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Assuming ProductId is INT column, what is the difference between writing 3 and N'3'?

They both work fine.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Products (ProductId, Name) VALUES (3,'Product3')

INSERT INTO dbo.Products (ProductId, Name) VALUES (N'3','Product3')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`N'3'` is a `nvarchar` type, where `3` is an `int`. If you're using `nvarchar` you're asking the parser to perform implicit conversion. In this case it works fine but in others you may run into casting problems.

Comment: +1: Bingo.  the nvarchar is used a lot for sending parameters, because anything will fit into it.  The problem, of course, is that anything will fit into it.

Answer (score 2):

When SQL Server encounters `N''`, it will treat the string as an `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`. `NVARCHAR` fields are unicode.

The reason `N'3'` still works for you is because it is converting it to `NVARCHAR`, and then doing an implicit conversion to `INT`.